# Ajax doesn't execute query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm a new with ajax and php. However, I tried inserting query with ajax and it's always showing error. Here is my index.php

```
<form onsubmit="return score.add();">
    <input type="text" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?=$accnt['user_id']?>"/>
    <input type="text" id="bet_input" name="bet_input" value="100" required/>
    <input type="submit" value="save"/>
</form>
<?php 
    switch ($_POST['req']) {
    case "score-add":
    echo $gameDB->addScore($_POST['bet_input'], $_POST['user_id']) ? "OK" : "ERR" ;
    break;
    }
?>
```

and this is my javascript

```
    <script >
var admin = {
    ajax: function (opt) {
    // admin.ajax() : do AJAX call
    // PARAM opt : options

        // DATA
        var data = new FormData();
        for (var key in opt.data) {
        data.append(key, opt.data[key]);
        }

        // AJAX
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', "index.php", true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
        if (typeof opt.load=="function") {
            opt.load(this.response);
        }
        };
        xhr.send(data);
    }
};
var score = {
    add : function() {
        admin.ajax({
        data : {
            req : "score-add",
            bet_input : document.getElementById("bet_input").value,
            user_id : document.getElementById("user_id").value
        },
        load : function (res) {
            if (res=="OK") { 
                alert("sss");
            }
            else { alert("xhr"); }
        }
        });
        return false;
    }
};
</script>
```

and this is my function

```
function addScore($bet_input,$user_id) {
    $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `bet_input` =? where `user_id` =?";
    $cond = [$bet_input, $user_id];
    return $this->exec($sql, $cond);
}
```

Also, I'd like to add some error message when executing ajax, is that possible?

Comment: You do not add an error handler

Comment: where should i add?

Comment: " it's always showing error." — What error?

Comment: what error is it showing ?